# Why am I unable to use my Mac to download this R package from GitHub?

Tags: r, macos

In Rstudio, I tried to run `remotes::install_github("PPBDS/primer.data")` in the console to download that package, and I got this error:

> Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  :
> download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/PPBDS/primer.data/tarball/HEAD' failed

I'm using a new mac with macOS Big Sur version 11.0.1, and I had just installed R and Rstudio. This command never gave me an error like this on my Windows machine, so what's causing the issue?

Comment: no way of knowing... is that the *entire* error message?

Comment: My guess is that you're missing some library involved in downloading the files (like curl?).

Comment: @hobbs  I mean, I guess the whole thing is:

`Downloading GitHub repo PPBDS/primer.data@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/PPBDS/primer.data/tarball/HEAD' failed`

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I only needed the `remotes` package and rtools40 when I was using my Windows machine. Is there something similar to rtools40 for mac? I couldn't find it online

Comment: Can you access that URL from your browser? Are you sure it's not some sort of network configuration thing? There's no rtools40 for mac. But you do need xcode tools installed and setup to build packages from source. Though that shouldn't effect just downloading the files. What version of R are you running?

Comment: @MrFlick I am using R version 4.1.0. Visitng that URL printed out on the error on my browser automatically starts a download for a `PPBDS-primer.data-24ac7f8.tar.gz` file.

Comment: That does seem odd. Have you tried to install other packages? Is it just this one that's giving you a problem? What does `options("download.file.method")` return in R? And what version of `remotes` are you using?

Comment: @MrFlick I was able to install `tidyverse`, `remotes`, and `usethis` just fine. All of these three packages are from CRAN. Running `options("download.file.method")` returns `$download.file.method [1] "libcurl"` in Rstudio. I have version 2.4.0 of `remotes`

Comment: Try `remotes::install_github("ppbds/primer.data")`. Note the casing

Comment: @Oliver Still got the same error.

Comment: This issue is not specific to your system. I am experiencing the same issue with the specific package. So that said, the long "work around" would be to: 1) clone the repo to your pc. 2) Open rstudio. 3) use `devtools::install('path to package clone')`. 4) Open an issue on their package page, describing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

This issue should be solved. Please use the normal command to try it out:

`remotes::install_github("PPBDS/primer.data")`

It turned out to be an indentation issue in the package DESCRIPTION file.

## Original Answer

An issue has been opened about this problem.
https://github.com/PPBDS/primer.data/issues/18

This problem happened because of the latest commit, we're still tracking down the specific problem.

For now, please use this command to install the primer.data package:

```
remotes::install_github("PPBDS/primer.data", ref = "24ac7f87e025b859a976fd6122f7c2ea8af5c713")
```

And follow the issue. After it's fixed, you can just remove and re-install with the intended command.